# Swift tableView cellForRowAt get array's subKeyName's array

Tags: swift

I have array data like this

```
var countryData = [Country(code: "01", name: "US", currency: "USD", information: [Information(first: "100", second: "200", third: "300"), information(first: "400", second: "500", third: "600"), information(first: "700", second: "800", third: "900")])]
```

I need to use tableView to show these data

In cellForRowAt I can get value of Country

like this

```
cell.countryNameLabel.text = countryData[indexPath.row].name
```

but what if there's subKay and it's array

How should I get that array's data and show all?

```
cell.countryInformationLabel.text = ?
```

My cell is look like

```
US : 100 200 300, 400 500 600,700 800 900
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
let information = countryData[indexPath.row].information
cell.countryInformationLabel.text = information
  .map { String(describing: $0) }
  .joined(separator: ", ")

extension Information: CustomStringConvertible {
  var decription: String {
    return "\(first) \(second) \(third)"
  } 
}
```

If you think it is unnecessary to conform to `CustomStringConvertible`, simply do this:

```
let information = countryData[indexPath.row].information
cell.countryInformationLabel.text = information
  .map { "\($0.first) \($0.second) \($0.third)" }
  .joined(separator: ", ")
```

The result is the following:

```
struct Information {
  var first: String
  var second: String
  var third: String
}

let information = [Information(first: "100", second: "200", third: "300"),
                   Information(first: "300", second: "400", third: "500"),
                   Information(first: "400", second: "500", third: "600")]
print(
  information
    .map { "\($0.first) \($0.second) \($0.third)" }
    .joined(separator: ", ")
)
// 100 200 300, 300 400 500, 400 500 600
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Model Object, information is an array. So, you have to run a loop over the information. Please try the following code this is work fine for me.

```
cell.countryNameLabel.text = countryData[indexPath.row].name
let informationArr = countryData[indexPath.row].information // This should be an array.
var countryInfoText = ""
for info in informationArr{
    countryInfoText += "\(info.first) \(info.second) \(info.third),"
}
cell.countryInformationLabel.text = countryInfoText
```